Role of VBUS on FTDI FT600Q
I am working on a PCB design using the FTDI FT600Q. Reading through the datasheet as well as the PCB Layout Guidelines - I cannot find any information on the voltage tolerance or role of VBUS.
In this design, I'm also using the TPS25730D for USB PD control to provide 5V-15V through VBUS.
I assume VBUS on the FT600Q cannot tolerate >5V (it's not documented anywhere I can see.. just an educated guess), but this design is extremely compact and ideally would not generate a guaranteed 5V rail just for this pin.
My two questions are:
What is the voltage tolerance of the VBUS pin on the FT600Q? If the answer is 5V max; what exactly is the purpose of the VBUS pin? Given it also takes in 3V3 for VCC and 3V3 or 1V8 for VCCIO. Knowing its purpose would allow me to answer if I can power it with 3V3, or possibly leave it disconnected entirely.

You should of course ask the manufacturer. The data sheet does not say.
However, I am going to make a guess that it cannot tolerate much higher than 5V, and it may tolerate up to 5V when the chip is unpowered.
I base my guess on the fact that the evaluation board divides down the ideal 5V to about 3.4V before sending it to the VBUS pin.
The connector on the eval board is also MicroUSB 3.0 which does not generally support higher than 5V - exceptions may apply if QC communication is used, but this FT60x series does not indicate any QC support, only BC which is 5V.
This resistive divider on VBUS is usually done on other FTDI chips in self-powered configurations, where the VBUS pin is not 5V tolerant while the chip is unpowered.
The VBUS pin is generally also a regulator input pin on bus-powered ICs, but with this chip it always requires external regulator, so the VBUS might simply be a GPIO pin.
USB chips like FT600 need to detect the VBUS being present or not, to be able to detect when cable is plugged or unplugged, or when PC goes to sleep or shuts down and VBUS disappears. The USB2 pull-up resistor must be disabled when VBUS goes away and the chip can freely go into sleep mode. When VBUS comes back, the chip must wake up and enable USB2 pull-up resistor, or rather before doing so, try negotiating USB3 link first and if it does not succeed then fall back to USB2 link.
Safe to say, no, do not expect it to tolerate more than 5V, and it may be best to use a resistive divider anyway.
Feel free to add some clamping like a zener to limit the pin voltage to 3.3, or enable it with a logic signal when PD negotiations are over and you get the VBUS voltage you wanted.
